# Find the AVPlayer associated with an AVPlayerItem

Tags: ios, avplayer

An AVPlayerItem can only ever be assigned to one AVPlayer.  Once an AVPlayerItem has been added to an AVPlayer, future attempts to add it to a different AVPlayer will SIGABRT the app.

So, given an AVPlayerItem, how can you determine:

1. What AVPlayer it is currently associated with? and
2. If it has ever been inserted into an AVPlayer at any point in the past?

The following code demonstrates the problem reliably:

```
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"]];
AVPlayer *firstPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
[firstPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
AVPlayer *secondPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
[secondPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
```

And here's the error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Ha, no. We took a different approach. When we're about to assign an AVPlayerItem of questionable lineage to an AVPlayer, we clone the item and broadcast a message that we're replacing the old one with the new one. We also use associated objects to point the old one to the new one. So if we get an old AVPlayerItem for which this procedure has already occurred, we can follow the linked list of forward associated object pointers to find the final "real" one. Thank you Apple.

Answer (score 8):

There is a semi-legal way that might break in the future. The player item has a private method (and, it seems, variable) named `_player`. You can query it like this (which technically doesn't use private API, so I think it should be AppStore-safe):

```
id player = [item valueForKey:@"_player"];
```

Comment: How to get the player of current played sound of webkit? Can you send the git link of private api?

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen: That's an unrelated question. Please ask a new question here on SO.

Comment: If you have any idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71912499/swift-getting-avplayer-from-webview

Comment: @DarkDust Am I correct in editing your answer to have an underscore in the key? I just tested to confirm and it seems to only work with the underscore on my end.. but wanted to double check with you.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: [`valueForKey:` looks for instance variables with underscores as well](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955), so it should not be necessary to prefix it. But it probably doesn't hurt and I doubt Apple's symbols scan for App Store submits is going to trigger on `_player`, so it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the other way round? Try accessing the details inside the item that is being played by the AVPlayer

```
AVPlayer *firstPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]init];
```

After which you can access `firstPlayer.currentItem` .This will give you access the `firstPlayer`'s `AVPlayerItem`.

Eg:

```
firstPlayer.currentItem.duration
```

will give you the duration of that track.

Comment: In my case, what I get is an AVPlayerItem.  It's possible that the item has been associated with an AVPlayer in the past.  My goal is to determine if that is the case.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an elegant solution, without private keys and associated objects. Create a custom player item:

```
class PlayerAwareItem {
    weak var player: AVPlayer?
}
```

Setup a player:

```
let item = PlayerAwareItem(asset: asset)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
item.player = player
```

Access the player whenever you have the item later (in this example we want to restart the player after stalling):

```
@objc func handlePlayerItemDidStall(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let playerItem = notification.object as? PlayerAwareItem,
        let player = playerItem.player else { return }
    player.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can associate an `AVPlayerItem` with an `AVPlayer` using:

```
static char playerKey;

objc_setAssociatedObject(item, &playerKey, player, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

and get it using:

```
objc_getAssociatedObject(item, &playerKey);
```

Comment: Just saw your comment @jimbojw. I am struggling with the same error and using a simple associated object doesn't resolve it. Will try the broadcast notification approach.

Comment: `#import <objc/runtime.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Based on Anil's answer, for a looped playback on multiple videos:

```
for (NSObject * obj in cachedVideos){
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[AVPlayerLayer class]]){
        AVPlayerLayer * layer = (AVPlayerLayer *)obj;
        if ([layer.player.currentItem isEqual:n.object]){
            [layer.player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
            [layer.player play];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```